# If and only if condition SQL -- SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm writing a SQL statement to select a user on a table if that user does not exist on another table, then I want to pull in all their data from another table then I'll be outputting all that in Coldfusion.

How do I do this? I have tried, my atempt is below:

pro_profile == All employees
mod_userStatus == All Professional Staff members
I am doing the not exists to remove professional stuff to just get our student staff. 
mod_StudentCertifications is a listing of the certifications they (students) hold.

If we do an AND statement between the where statements it returns no users, or only users that meet both conditions, if we do an OR it will return users with only 1 condition. I need it first Match the not exists then proceed to the exists statement.

Is that do able?

Here's my Statement:

```
SELECT profileID, firstName, lastName
FROM pro_Profile
WHERE not exists (
         SELECT profileID
         FROM mod_userStatus
         WHERE mod_userStatus.profileID = pro_Profile.profileID
        )             
        OR            
        exists (
          SELECT          
            cprAdultExp,
            cprInfantChildExp,
            cprFPRExp,
            aedExp,
            firstAidExp,
            emtExp,
            waterSafetyInstructionExp,
            bloodPathogensExp,
            oxygenAdminExp,
            lifegaurdingExp,
            wildernessResponderExp,
            notes
         FROM mod_StudentCertifications
         WHERE mod_StudentCertifications.profileID = pro_Profile.profileID       

        );
```

Comment: Based on using the AND (rather than the OR) -- you don't have data that matches.  Either you need to create it, or review your criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a "complete" pull:

```
SELECT p.profileID, p.firstName, p.lastName, sc.cprAdultExp, sc.....
FROM pro_Profile AS p
   LEFT OUTER JOIN mod_StudentCertifications AS sc ON sc.profileID = p.profileID
WHERE p.profileID NOT IN
    (
       SELECT profileID
       FROM mod_userStatus
    )
;
```

For a single "profile" pull:

```
SELECT p.profileID, p.firstName, p.lastName, sc.cprAdultExp, sc.....
FROM pro_Profile AS p
   LEFT OUTER JOIN mod_StudentCertifications AS sc ON sc.profileID = p.profileID
WHERE p.profileID = ?
    AND p.profileID NOT IN      
    (
       SELECT profileID
       FROM mod_userStatus
       WHERE profileID = ?
    )
;
```

EDIT: Looked at the execution plan of using a LEFT OUTER JOIN for mod_userStatus and checking it's primary key for null VS a NOT IN statement in a similar setup. The NOT IN statement is indeed less costly.

The LEFT OUTER JOIN performs a filter & hash match (Cost: 2.984):
[image]

While the NOT IN performs a merge join (Cost: 1.508):
[image]

Comment: `IN` doesn't support more than one column for comparison, which might not work for the `EXISTS` portion.  But the SELECT clause of an EXISTS isn't evaluated anyway...

Comment: @OMG Ponies Edited after I saw what the OP was after. Thanks!

Comment: You mean you copied the OPs answer, stating things worked by using a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Simply re-read the question and fixed my own mistake. No need to be uncivil. Mental note to fully flush out my answer in the future :) AS I say that I see something else to improve... eek!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question.  But I *think* you're trying to do this:

```
SELECT PROF.profileID, 
       PROF.firstName, 
       PROF.lastName
       CERT.cprAdultExp,
       CERT.cprInfantChildExp,
       CERT.cprFPRExp,
       CERT.aedExp,
       CERT.firstAidExp,
       CERT.emtExp,
       CERT.waterSafetyInstructionExp,
       CERT.bloodPathogensExp,
       CERT.oxygenAdminExp,
       CERT.lifegaurdingExp,
       CERT.wildernessResponderExp,
       CERT.notes
  FROM pro_Profile AS PROF INNER JOIN mod_StudentCertifications AS CERT
      ON PROF.profileID = CERT.profileID
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT profileID FROM mod_userStatus 
         WHERE mod_userStatus.profileID = pro_Profile.profileID)
```

This pulls information from pro_Profile and mod_StudentCertifications only for those individuals whose profile is not in mod_userStatus.

You can simplify the WHERE clause further like this:

```
WHERE PROF.profileID NOT IN (SELECT profileID FROM mod_UserStatus)
```

Also, if this is not yet a production database and you have control over the structure, you might consider refactoring the certification table so that each experience type is a separate row in a related table.

Comment: Okay, I guess I _did_ understand what you were trying to do, looking at the similarity of my answer and what you wound up using yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up doing an left join, as the table (Pro_Profile) is the main one required and it worked!

```
            SELECT
            pro_Profile.profileID,
            pro_Profile.firstName,
            pro_Profile.lastName,
            mod_StudentCertifications.cprAdultExp,
            mod_StudentCertifications.cprInfantChildExp,
            mod_StudentCertifications.cprFPRExp,
            mod_StudentCertifications.aedExp,
            mod_StudentCertifications.firstAidExp,
            mod_StudentCertifications.emtExp,
            mod_StudentCertifications.waterSafetyInstructionExp,
            mod_StudentCertifications.bloodPathogensExp,
            mod_StudentCertifications.oxygenAdminExp,
            mod_StudentCertifications.lifegaurdingExp,
            mod_StudentCertifications.wildernessResponderExp,
            mod_StudentCertifications.notes
        FROM 
            pro_Profile
        LEFT JOIN mod_StudentCertifications
        ON
            mod_StudentCertifications.profileID = pro_Profile.profileID   
        WHERE not exists (
            SELECT 
                profileID
            FROM 
                mod_userStatus
            WHERE
                  mod_userStatus.profileID = pro_Profile.profileID
        );
```

Comment: You can simplify that WHERE clause as well, see my answer elsewhere in this question.